# How to Add and Remove UIButtons in SubView using UISilder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uislider

I have a `subview` which is allmost half to my mainview and also I have a `UISlider` on my mainview . My silder has a value from 0 to 10. i want to add some `UIButton`s to my `Subview` with the `UISilder`.Now if my silder get the value 2 then i want to add 2 `UIButton`s to my Subview as if my silder pass the value 2 and gets the value 4 then I want to remove  the previous `UIButton`s from Subview and Add some new `UIButton`s to Subview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The code is untested.

1. Initiate a 10 `UIButton` and add them to the view, set them as hidden:

   ```
   for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
       UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, x * 100, 100, 50)];
       [btn setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",(x + 1)]];
       [btn setHidden:true];
       [self.view addObject:btn];
       [btn release];
   }
   ```
2. Use the slider change value method to hide/show the buttons like this:

   ```
       -(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{
             UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
             for (int x = 0; x < slider.value; x++) {
                  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[savedBtn objectAtIndex:x];
                  [btn setHidden:false];
             }
       }
   ```

**Update**

To use a `UIScrollView`, you have to add the `UIButton`s to the scrollView instead of the view, like this:

```
    UIScrollView *sView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)];
    [sView setDelegate:self];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, x * 100, 100, 50)];
        [btn setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",(x + 1)]];
        [btn setHidden:true];
        [sView addSubview:btn];
        [btn release];
    }
```

then add the scrollView to the view:

```
     [self.view addSubview:sView];
```

hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanx @Scar your answers solve my basic problem.Can you  please help me more about scrolling of view,because my subview has hight 100 so that why its show me only three buttons and my fourth button and fifth button has y.xis 130,150 so plz suggest me how to solve this problem.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

First of all you add a selector method to your `UISlider`,

```
[customSlider addTarget:selfaction:@selector(sliderEnd:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now the selector method is supposed to be defined in the `Mainview` class of your project.

Now in the selector method you determine the slider value in the function, and depending on its value you may add or remove or add buttons to the other view. You can store the reference to all the button when you add them to your view and then remove them from `superview` when the slider value suggests to do so.

Hope it helps.